# How do I specify the WS-Addressing version with a JAX-WS client?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, ws-addressing

I generated a SOAP 1.2 web service client with wsimport (JDK 1.7). I need it to explicitly use WS-Addressing 2004/08 and not 2005/08.
The closest I could find for instanciating the client was

```
import MyService.*;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService service = new MyService();  
        IMyService proxy = service.getMyService(new javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature(true, true) );  
        ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://192.168.0.5:1234/services/MyService");
        proxy.Ping("Foo");
      }
}
```

The important bit being

```
MyService service = new MyService();
IMyService proxy = service.getMyService(new javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature(true, true));
```

Unfortunately, this results in 2005/08 addressing.  Not supplying an argument to getMyService() results in not using WS-Addressing.

The only examples I can find on Google that force 2004/08 Addressing use Axis2 (the whole reason I want JAX-WS is to move away from Axis2)

The difference on the wire is
(2004/08)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.example.com/schemas/service/myservice/IMyService/Ping</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:87727401-b1a0-4667-9ef0-c64e58800ff6</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://192.168.0.5:1234/services/MyService</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Ping xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/service/myservice">
            <Message>Foo</Message>
        </Ping>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

(2005/08)

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://192.168.0.5:1234/services/MyService</To>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" S:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.example.com/schemas/service/myservice/IMyService/Ping</Action>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:87727401-b1a0-4667-9ef0-c64e58800ff6</MessageID>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <Ping xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/service/myservice">
            <Message>Foo</Message>
        </Ping>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: I'm wondering... should you bother with doing this on the application level or would it have made more sense to do it on an ESB (e.g. DataPower) level and let your application presume that the data it receives is clean (just to offload the work).

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do this, but I'm not convinced that it's the best solution.

It involves creating a custom SOAPHandler and manually injecting the Addressing headers and stripping out the HTTP header soapaction

```
public static class Addressing2004SoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
    private String mEndpoint;

    public Addressing2004SoapHandler(String endpoint) {
        super();
        mEndpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public Set<QName> getHeaders()
    {
        Set<QName> retval = new HashSet<QName>();
        retval.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "Action"));
        retval.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "MessageID"));
        retval.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "ReplyTo"));
        retval.add(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "To"));
        return retval;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext)
    {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)messageContext.get (MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            try {
                messageContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Collections.singletonMap("Content-Type",Collections.singletonList("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8")));
                SOAPMessage message = messageContext.getMessage();
                if(message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader() == null) {
                        message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
                }
                SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
                SOAPHeaderElement actionElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "Action"));
                actionElement.setMustUnderstand(true);
                String action = (String)messageContext.get("javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri");
                messageContext.put("javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri", null);
                actionElement.addTextNode(action);
                header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "MessageID")).addTextNode("uuid:" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                SOAPHeaderElement replyToElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "ReplyTo"));
                SOAPElement addressElement = replyToElement.addChildElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "Address"));
                addressElement.addTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2004/08/addressing/anonymous");
                SOAPHeaderElement toElement = header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "To"));
                toElement.setMustUnderstand(true);
                String endpoint = (String)messageContext.get("javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address");
                toElement.addTextNode(endpoint);
            }
            catch(SOAPException ex) {
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext messageContext)
    {
            return true;
    }
    public void close(MessageContext messageContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the updated test Class

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService service = new MyService();  
        IMyService proxy = service.getMyService();  
        javax.xml.ws.Binding binding = ((BindingProvider)proxy).getBinding();
        List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
        handlerList.add(new Addressing2004SoapHandler(endpoint));
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://192.168.0.5:1234/services/MyService");
        proxy.Ping("Foo");
    }
}
```

There is a side effect, I've not yet figured out how to solve, this results in a <?xml version="1.0"?> xml declaration which conflicts with the HTTP Content-type.  I'll post an update when I've figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MemberSubmissionAddressingFeature from jaxws-rt

`IMyService proxy = service.getMyService(new com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionAddressingFeature(true, true) );`

this is the pom file dependency for maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.7